# Can you be healed or stabilized (if downed) while petrified?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, healing, hit-points

I just posted [this question about whether you continue making death saving throws while petrified if you are at 0 HP](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/142535/do-you-continue-making-death-saving-throws-while-petrified#142535). The answer was yes. But I thought of another question:

If you are downed and petrified, you must still make death saving throws. Can you receive healing or Medicine checks in order to stabilize you (so you stop making death saving throws) while in this condition?

In addition, if you survive, are you able to recover hit points either by healing magic (from other PC), potions, taking a long rest, or spending hit dice on a short rest? I mean, are you able to recover hit points by any source of healing while petrified?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Yes you can be healed or stabilised while petrified

The condition petrified states the following:

> - A petrified creature is transformed, along with any nonmagical object is is wearing of carrying, into a solid inanimate substance (usually stone). Its weight increases by a factor of ten, and it ceases aging.
> - The creature is incapacitated (see the condition), can't move or speak, and is unaware of its surroundings.
> - Attacks rolls against the creature have advantage.
> - The creature automatically fails Strength and Dexterity savings throws.
> - The creature is immune to poison and disease, although a poison or disease already in its system is suspend, not neutralized.

There is no restriction placed on healing or casting spells on a petrified creature. You are still a creature, you can be targeted by attacks so you can be targeted by healing too, as (unofficially) confirmed by [this tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/966507846664781824):

> Neither the petrified condition nor the flesh to stone spell turns you into an object. You are a creature subjected to the petrified condition (PH, 291). #DND

<sup>Thanks @Rubiksmoose for the link</sup>

You cannot take actions or bonus action as you are incapacitated so you can't heal yourself other than by taking a short or long rest. Healing spells from others and potions will still work.

Comment: You neglect the case of mundane healing (eg. stabilizing via Medicine checks), which is fair to assume would be problematic while your organs are made of stone.

Comment: I wonder if potions will actually work here. That might be up to the DM because being turned into solid stone eg with your mouth closed would leave no way to get the potion into you. Also I'm not sure you can "drink" it in that state. Likely entirely a DM call.

Answer (score -6):

Logic says you cannot, and that is how we treat petrification in LARP.

The D&D rules are most likely not explicit on this particular case. However, the fact that poisons and diseases are suspended (but not eliminated) gives us a hint for a ruling.

First, in petrified state you **are** stabilized. Both logic and the fact that aging, poison, disease and even awareness of the surrounding are all stopped indicates that bleeding is not going to happen any more.

Secondly, a good (IMHO) ruling would be that healing spells etc. can be cast on your while petrified, but they are arrested the same way poisons are, and will come into effect once the petrification ceases. Note that time still runs, so if the spells are expired by the time you turn back to flesh & blood (or are instant), then they won't have effect.

That last is important for consistency, because otherwise all **harmfull** spells would also have to be delayed and come into effect when you turn back.

Comment: The rules are explicit. It works. Don't try to assume real world logic for DND rules.

Comment: What logic are you using besides the effects that say aging and poisons are paused? What logic could possibly be used here? Being turned to stone by magic is not a logical effect as far as I know. So what is your train of thought there? You keep saying that logic agrees with you but you never explain how or why.

Comment: One side effect of your second ruling by the way, seems to be that you would not be able to use any spell that would heal the petrified condition (even though some explicitly are designed to do this). This makes this condition way more powerful and essentially inescapable.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I'm quite sure they explicitly say that they undo the petrified condition and are thus more specific than a general ruling.

Comment: @linksassin Yeah, one of the reasons I play very little D&D. The rules are trying to be precise but fail to do so.

Comment: @Tom I think that is a frustration we definitely all share.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose finding loopholes was cute when I was 17. Now it's annoying. We found a loophole in Shadowrun 1st Edition that would allow a single mage to reliably destroy a main battle tank at the cost of medium injury from the backlash. We don't do that anymore, our RPGs aren't logic-free zones now that we're adults.